# How to kill a Thread or Process in Wildfly 16?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, kill-process, wildfly-16

I have a scheduler deployment. Sometimes scheduler get stuck in such a way that we are not able to disable or Undeploy the deployables from Wildfly UI.

Get xyz messages like:

```
2020-02-26 05:28:18,181 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 209) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentRemoveHandler$1@383e9941 for operation remove at address [("deployment" => "Snow-1.11-SNAPSHOT.war")] failed handling operation rollback -- java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0345: Timeout after 5 seconds waiting for existing service service jboss.deployment.unit."Snow-1.11-SNAPSHOT.war".contents to be removed so a new instance can be installed.: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0345: Timeout after 5 seconds waiting for existing service service jboss.deployment.unit."Snow-1.11-SNAPSHOT.war".contents to be removed so a new instance can be installed.
```

I would like to Kill particular process either from backend or front end especially stucked process in wildfly, in place or removing timers or restarting server groups.

Can you please suggest how to do the same? (Using wildfly 16 and Linux)

Comment: Do you create the thread or is the thread managed by the container?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins
Container does that. But COntainer is not taking instruction on Disable or Undeploy when particular thread got stuck. It only listens restart. So what way i can get that thread info and kill him while container is up

Comment: I think you'd need to find out why the `Snow-1.11-SNAPSHOT.war` is not shutting down. This is likely due to something in the deployment still running which doesn't allow the service to stop.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: Well that is problem, if something is already running and like it needs to run for say 2 hours, why is server not allowing to Disable or Undeploy application in Wildfly 16. When we click disable or undeploy it should immediately do that. So i was finding the way to kill the thread first, inside wildfly only as undeploy or disable is not doing it for me.

Comment: It depends on what's running to be honest. The server can only control the services it starts. For example if a deployed application has a thread it creates doing something WildFly cannot control that thread.